# Is There A Way I Can Make A Textarea Fullscreen Without An Extra CSS File?

Tags: html, textarea, width

I Want To Make A TextArea Fullscreen Without An Addon CSS File And Without Removing The Text?

```html
<html>
<title>TextArea</title>
<body>
<textarea spellcheck="true"></textarea>
<p>TextArea</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
   <title>TextArea</title>
   <body>
      <textarea spellcheck="true" style="width: 100%;
         height: 100vh;"></textarea>
      <p>TextArea</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can add inline styles if you don't want to create a separate CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline styles:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fullscreen Textarea</title>

  <body style="width:100px; height:100px;">
    <textarea style="width: 100%; height:100%;"></textarea>
  </body>

</html>
```

Or, use a `<style>` tag:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fullscreen textarea</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
</body>
<style>
  body {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  #textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

</html>
```

Both have the same effect, but it is best practice not to use inline styles when possible.